# Issue installing xlwings to use Python with excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Writing this question with a last hope of trying to get xlwings installed. I have seen various video on youtube to do it and also read articles about it. I am still not able to install and run my python scripts from excel. I am working on Windows10, to install xlwings when i write the command: pip install xlwings, it works and I can see it was installed.

```
C:\Users\I547565>pip install xlwings
Collecting xlwings
  Using cached xlwings-0.24.7.tar.gz (786 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=224 in c:\users\i547565\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from xlwings) (301)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for xlwings, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: xlwings
    Running setup.py install for xlwings ... done
Successfully installed xlwings-0.24.7
```

When i go to install the addin it gives me error that xlwings is not recognized.

```
C:\Users\I547565>xlwings addin install
'xlwings' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Any help in this regard, as to how to get xlwings to work would be much much much appreciated. I am at my wits end to make this work.

Comment: Try installing the wheel package and reinstall xlwings - the legacy script may be broken.  It's also possible the <pythonroot>/Scripts directory when the xlwings script will be installed is not on your system %PATH%.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it might be an enviroment issue. It appear like it does not find xlwings installed properly.

First of all, have you installed Anaconda/Miniconda ? if so, is it installed as "single user" or as "all users" ? in this latter case you have to install packages using conda-CMD as administrator.

Try to unistall numpy, pandas and xlwings with eg.:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip uninstall pandas
pip uninstall xlwings
```

And then install them in sequence with conda as:

```
conda install numpy
conda install pandas
conda install xlwings
```

It might be useless, but, in many cases I found funny errors due to missing dependences with numpy-pandas and xlwings.

After that, when you're sure xlwings works fine, you install the addin:

```
xlwings addin install
```

Worth giving a try, my two cents.